# Missing { inserted. Error.Please Help me with this equation

Tags: math-mode, errors

[image]

I would like to write above equation in my document. But I am getting Missing { error. Please help me with this code.

```
\begin{equation}  
\vec{X}(t+1)={\vec{D}^'\.$e^{bl}$\.\cos(2$\pi$l)+\vec{X}^*(t)}
\end{equation}
```

Answer (score 6):

So, you have several problems with your code:

- you use `^'` while the simple `'` is sufficient
- you use `\.` instead of `\cdot`
- you use the mathematical shift `$` inside of an equation (which is unnecessary)
- you don't provide a minimal example

Here is an example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}  
\vec{X}(t+1)=\vec{D'}\cdot e^{bl}\cdot \cos(2\pi l)+\vec{X^{*}}(t)
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

which produces

[image]

If you want longer arrows you could use `\renewcommand{\vec}{\overrightarrow}`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\renewcommand{\vec}{\overrightarrow}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}  
\vec{X}(t+1)=\vec{D'}\cdot e^{bl}\cdot \cos(2\pi l)+\vec{X^{*}}(t)
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest `\vv` from the `esvect` package. It has `8` arrow tips ( from `a` to `h`, which do not touch capital letters, and are extensible. Here are some examples:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[b]{esvect}
\renewcommand{\vec}{\overrightarrow}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\vec{X}(t+1)=\vec{D'}\cdot e^{bl}\cdot \cos(2\pi l)+\vec{X^{*}}(t)
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\vv{X}(t+1)=\vv{D'}\cdot e^{bl}\cdot \cos(2\pi l)+\vv{X^{*}}(t)
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Option b:
[image]

Option d (default):
[image]

Option f:
[image]